# Fixing starting times command by command and globally

Tags: python

I have a lot of `Command` objects. Each command has lots of `Task` objects. Tasks and commands are related. Each command wants to know which task belongs to it. Where each task wants to know which command it belongs to.

```py
class Command:

    def __init__(self, date):
        self.deadline = date
        self.tasks = []

    def add_task(self, task:Task):
        """
        add a task to this command
        """
        self.tasks.append(task)
        return task

    def has_task(self, task):
        return task in self.tasks

    def remove_task(self, task):
        """
        Remove the task from this command.  After calling this, 
        the task is orphaned and the reference to the task should be discarded.
        """
        self.tasks.remove(task)


class Task:
    def __init__(self, command:Command, duration:int):
        self.duration = duration
        self._command = command

    @property
    def command(self):
        """
        Getter for self._command with sanity checking that 
        the task is not orphaned.
        """
        if not self._command.has_task(self):
            raise ValueError("orphaned task")
        return self._command

class Problem:
    def __init__(self, commands:Dict[str,Command], tasks:Dict[str,Task]):
        self._commands = commands
        self._tasks = tasks
```

In the `Problem` object I feel there is some redundancy in the data between `Command`s and `Task`s.

I fix starting times in two ways:

1. Fix the start time of tasks command by command.
   This is why is a `commands` attribute in `Problem`.
2. Merge them and then fix the starting times.
   This is why there is `tasks` attribute in `Problem`.

I need both ways to fix starting times. However, fixing the starting time of a task always depends on the deadline of the command to which it belongs.

I'm unsure if my design is good. Sometimes I need to go through the tasks command by command. Sometimes I need to consider all the tasks for the command they belong.
Is there a design pattern I can use?

Comment: @Peilonrayz I fixed it

Comment: Thank you :D looks good

Answer (score 1):

### Maintaining bidirectional relationships

Rather than this check:

```
    if not self._command.has_task(self):
        raise ValueError("orphaned task")
```

it would be better to mark the task as orphaned by nulling out its command. In other words,

```
def remove_task(self, task):
    """
    Remove the task from this command.  After calling this, 
    the task is orphaned and the reference to the task should be discarded.
    """
    task.command = None
    self.tasks.remove(task)
```

Having `command` as a simple, "public", possibly-None member on `Task` is simpler. At most, I would give this a type hint of `Optional[Command]` in the constructor.

### Types

Don't call `date` `date`; that's a commonly used class in a built-in library.

`deadline` should probably be of type `datetime` (not `date`), and `duration` should be of type `timedelta`, not `int`.